# TcpClientActivex capture to picturebox

Tags: vb.net

Hello i'm trying to make an automated camera capture using TcpClientActivex control. I'm still a beginner at vb.net. But i don't know how to capture it then set the picturebox image.

I can use `TcpClientActivex.GetImage.Save("location")` though but i don't wanna save it into file, i want to set it to picturebox using codes without saving the file. I tried researching for it but the results are not what i was looking for...

i tried `TcpClientActivex.GetImage.Save(picturebox1.image)`

and

```
 TcpClientActivex.GetImage.SaveAdd(picturebox1.image
```

but didn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Did you try ***assigning*** the image to the picture box?

```
PictureBox1.Image = TcpClientActivex.GetImage()
```

Please read up on the [**Assignment Operator**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/assignment-operator). You might also want to find yourself a tutorial or book to get a grasp of the basic concepts of VB.NET and *Object-oriented programming*.